# Сравнение с NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, null

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_table t
WHERE
  t.a = :a AND
  t.b = :b AND
  t.c = :c AND
  t.d = :d
```

Все поля целочисленные. На все четыре поля построен общий индекс. Но как поля так и параметры могут принимать значение `NULL`. В этом случае должно выполняться правило "Все равно NULL". Есть ли красивый способ решения проблемы кроме добавления наборов `OR IS NULL`?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_table t
WHERE
  (t.a = :a OR t.a IS NULL OR :a IS NULL) AND
  (t.b = :b OR t.b IS NULL OR :b IS NULL) AND
  (t.c = :c OR t.c IS NULL OR :c IS NULL) AND
  (t.d = :d OR t.d IS NULL OR :d IS NULL)
```

В принципе, задачу можно упростить, сказав, что все параметры и поля `a`, `b` не могут быть равны NULL.

Запрос этот будет выполняться часто, поэтому требуется максимальное быстродействие. Допустимо использовать хранимые процедуры

СУБД Oracle

Comment: Тогда лучше упростите и не используйте NULL в `a` и `b`. Потому что если скажем `a` первое в индексе и будет условие `:a  is null` (т.е. не обращаем внимание на поле `a`) то индекс заведомо не сможет использоваться.

Comment: Используйте coalesce

Comment: *В этом случае должно выполняться правило "Все равно NULL"* `WHERE COALESCE(t.a, :a, -1) = COALESCE(:a, t.a, -1)`. Где "-1" - значение, в принципе невозможное ни в значении поля, ни в значении условия отбора. Вот только с "максимальным быстродействием" будут напряги...

Comment: @JVic @Akina `COALESCE` угробит все индескы

Comment: @Mike а потом остальные поля перечислить через `OR IS NULL`? Кстати вопрос, а если писать так `NOT(t.a <> :a) AND
  NOT (t.b <> :b) AND
  NOT (t.c <> :c) AND
  NOT (t.d <> :d)` Если не ошибаюсь, то запрос должен работать правильно. А что с индексами получится?

Comment: что то мне подсказывает что индексы на неравенство не будут применены. но лучше все проверять, иногда оптимизатор удивляет своей умностью (а иногда тупостью)

Comment: Короче, не приходит ничего умного в голову. Давайте вы запретите полю таблицы быть `NULL` ;) Тогда `t.a = nvl(:a, t.a)` спасет отца русской демократии.

Comment: "параметры могут принимать значение NULL" - вот это не совсем понятно. А какой смысл параметера, если его значение NULL?  Запрос динамический или статический?

Comment: @0xdb Конечно, статический. Это процедура в базе

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Из вопроса это не совсем понятно, в тело процедуры нельзя связанные переменные добавить, т.е. будет не :а, а что-то типа val_a. Но не в этом суть. Возможно самое простое,  переделать  на динамический запрос,

Comment: @0xdb В любом случает остается вопрос, что делать с NULL в базе? Это основная проблема

Comment: Да, но binds с null большая из проблем потому, что не знаю как заставить какой либо индекс работать. Надо ещё подумать.

Comment: @0xdb Если так проще, то хорошо, считаем, что все входные параметры NOT NULL

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Хорошо, но тогда и проблема отпадает,  `where t.a = :a and t.b = :b and ...`, и всё будет будет работать, включая индексы.

Comment: @0xdb В базе поля могут быть NULL. Тогда эти поля не должны участвовать в сравнении

Comment: @AntonShchyrov При такой записи `t.a = :a` значения NULL в поле `a` из выборки будут исключены, это стандарт SQL.

Comment: @0xdb Вот именно. А мне нужно **выбрать** эти записи, а не исключить. Перечитайте вопрос. Мне нужно `(t.a = :a OR t.a IS NULL)  AND ...`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Раньше я так и понял, но "Тогда эти поля не должны участвовать в сравнении" сбило с толку. То есть нужен индекс, который будет учитывать NULL. Сколько строк с NULL относительно общего колличества строк?

Comment: @0xdb Поле a оказалось, NOT NULL. Поле b << 1%, поле с сейчас 85% NULL, но в процессе жизни системы этот процент будет падать. В идеале до нуля. Поле d ~ 20% NULL и тоже ожидается падение. Записей порядка миллиона

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74097/discussion-between-0xdb-and-anton-shchyrov).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как одно из простых решений, создать [функциональнй индекс](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/indexes-and-index-organized-tables.html#GUID-9AD7651D-0F0D-4FC6-A984-5845F0224EE6). Функция для индекса должна вернуть детерминированое уникальное значение для всех колонок участвующих в условии запроса. Алгоритм получения этих значений может быть любой, например, как [в этом топике на англ. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1358468). Для примера взял самый простой - конкантинация символьных представлений всех аргументов функции. Рассмотрим на воспроизводимом примере ниже.

Подготовка схемы:

```
create table mytab as
select
    ceil (level/5) a,
    case when mod (level,100) != 0 then level*10 end b,
    case when mod (level,8)   != 0 then level*10 end c
from dual connect by level <= 1e6
/
create or replace function mytabhash (
    a number, b number, c number) return varchar2 deterministic is
begin
    return (
        case when a is not null then to_char (a) else 'n' end||'|'||
        case when b is not null then to_char (b) else 'n' end||'|'||
        case when c is not null then to_char (c) else 'n' end);
end;
/
create index idx_mytab_hash on mytab (mytabhash (a,b,c))
/
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (user, 'mytab', cascade=>true)
/
```

Сам запрос и его результат:

```
SQL> set lines 999 autotrace on
SQL> var a number
SQL> var b number
SQL> var c number
SQL> exec :a:=40; :b:=1990; :c:=1990;

SQL> select a, b, c
  2  from mytab
  3  where mytabhash (a, b, c) = mytabhash (:a, :b, :c)
  4  /

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
        40       1990       1990
```

План и статистика выполнения:

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 763475804
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                |     1 |    37 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| MYTAB          |     1 |    37 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX_MYTAB_HASH |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("DB"."MYTABHASH"("A","B","C")="MYTABHASH"(:A,:B,:C))

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          5  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        464  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        500  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

---

**Важно:** возможное нарушение детерминантности результата функции из-за национальных настроек при преобразовании `to_char (numValue)`, в этом ответе не рассматривается.

Comment: Супер! То что было нужно.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Ну не совсем то, что было в вопросе. Скорее, одно из направлений, куда и как можно двигаться с похожей задачей.

Answer (score 0):

Вот это должно сработать:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_table t
WHERE
  nvl(t.a,nvl(:a,0)) = nvl(:a,nvl(t.a,0)) AND
  nvl(t.b,nvl(:b,0)) = nvl(:b,nvl(t.b,0)) AND
  nvl(t.c,nvl(:c,0)) = nvl(:c,nvl(t.c,0)) AND
  nvl(t.d,nvl(:d,0)) = nvl(:d,nvl(t.d,0))
```

Но с точки зрения производительности можно будет сказать только зная предполагаемый размер таблицы, как часто туда будут вставляться данные и из какого количества сессий.
Только тогда можно будет принять решения о необходимости создания индексов, партицирования или вообще отказаться от такого дизайна.

Comment: Запрос рабочий, но он мне нравится еще меньше, чем мой с ORами

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробоват сделать так.

Строить динамический запрос.

Если параметр равен `NULL`, его в запрос не включать.

Если поле равно `NULL`, использовать `nvl`.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_table t
WHERE
  nvl(t.a,:a)=:a AND
  nvl(t.b,:b)=:b AND
  nvl(t.d,:d)=:d
```

Здесь примем, что параметр `c` был `NULL`.

Comment: И Full scan по миллиону записей?

Comment: Почему Full scan?

Comment: А как Вы заставите использовать индексы?

Comment: Вы попробуйте, посмотрите план выпонления запроса.